# Object does not match target type exception when using a base class list

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection

I have three classes that are setup as follows. I want to get an array of the property **values** from the base class for all of the subclasses in the list of a base type.

```
public abstract class Base
{
  ...   
}

public class A : Base
{
  ...
}

public class B : Base
{
  ...
}
```

So my code looks like this where `list1<Base>` is a list containing elements of both type `A` and `B`:

```
List<PropertyInfo> props = new List<PropertyInfo>();
foreach(property in typeOf(Base).GetProperties())
{
   props.add(property)
}

foreach (var ele in list1)
{
   var propsArray = props.Select(prop => prop.GetValue(ele, null)).ToArray();
   ...
}
```

It has no problem for the first item it encounters, whether it is `A` or `B`, but then it has a problem with the second if it is the opposite type.

Here is the stack trace.

```
System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type.
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object target)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,    Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder   binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetValue(Object obj, Object[] index)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are you setting props?

Comment: `prop` does not match the runtime type of `ele`. Use the debugger to confirm. Make no mistake: GetValue does not have bugs. The arguments are wrong.

Comment: You aren't really showing anything. No members of the classes, no `list1`, no `props`... are we supposed to guess?

Comment: @wdavo I added updates to how I set prop. I can see the runtime of ele is either A or B as expected but that should be ok, right?

Comment: @Jon its psuedocode - I explained what is in list1 and I edited  to show how props populates - members of the classes should be irrelevant.

Comment: Looks like it should work... are you sure A and B really inherit Base?

Comment: Just tried it, and it works for me...

Comment: A simple example works just fine.  Perhaps the actual properties in Base matter.  Given previous comments, I'd say that you haven't given enough information for us to discover where your code is having problems.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. It pointed me in the correct direction which was legacy code setting props with a different type.